# Не могу запустить MySQL CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, centos7

Добрый день StackOverflow

У меня возникла проблема с сервером MySQL, устанавливал все по этому мануалу

[Мануал](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7)

Проблема возникла на этапе запуска сервера MySQL

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found.
```

До этого стояла mariaDB, возможно что проблема в этом?

Вывод systemctl list-units

```
 mysqld.service      not-found failed failed    mysqld.service
```

Вывод  yum list installed | grep mysql

```
    mysql-community-client.x86_64      8.0.15-1.el7               @mysql80-community
    mysql-community-common.x86_64      8.0.15-1.el7               @mysql80-community
    mysql-community-libs.x86_64        8.0.15-1.el7               @mysql80-community
    mysql-community-server.x86_64      8.0.15-1.el7               @mysql80-community
    mysql80-community-release.noarch   el7-2                      installed
```

Логи MySQL пустые

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, в каталоге */lib/systemd/system/* у Вас нет файла *mysqld.service*.

Именно его ищет *systemctl* когда пытается запустить сервис.

По идее, этот файл должен был быть создан при инсталляции MySQL. Почему этого не произошло - сказать трудно. Но что-то у Вас пошло не так.

Если есть возможность - просмотрите логи инсталляции на предмет сообщения об этом файле.